# Is there a relation between the number of partitions/Buckets in a hive table and the number of map tasks it launches for any operation on this data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, partitioning, mapper

I know that the number of map tasks is the same as the number of input splits given by the input format. When performing an operation on a partitioned or bucketed hive table how does the InputFormat class calculate input Splits as the data is in the form of files in a directory for partitioned or bucketed data? Is there any relation between the input splits(number of map tasks) and the number of partitions or buckets?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'sortof'.. hive delegates the splits to hadoop, and hadoop only cares about how much data is in that partitions, not really about partitions and buckets. The amount of data depends *indirectly* on the number of partitions, so to answer your question more correctly, it does *not* *directly* depend on the number of partitions.

When executing a query, to make the splits hive uses by default [CombineHiveInputFormat](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/CombineHiveInputFormat.html) 
which is actually only a wrapper around Hadoop's `CombineFileInputFormat`.
So actually hive will delegate to hadoop how to make the splits.

Hadoop's `CombineFileInputFormat` will group smaller files together so the splits will be according to what's configured as minimum split size.
Note that it belongs to hadoop, not hive, therefore has no knowledge of buckets, but it will just group files based on their size and locality (rack, etc), since it's better of a split is actually all on the same node or at least on the same rack.

You can have a look at how the splits are created [in the function getSplits here](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.java%7C%7Cjava+file+++dos).